# AppCompat Force Holo Theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am creating an app and have discovered the Holo Dark theme (I am using it for my dialog).  After looking at it, I would like to change my entire app to look like the Holo theme.  The problem is, on run I get an error that tells me that I have to use an AppCompat theme, but I cannot find an AppCombat.Holo theme!  Does anyone out there know how to force AppCompat to use a Holo theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` cannot use a native Holo theme. Your choices are:

1. Switch to `Activity`, remove `appcompat-v7` from your project, and use a theme based off of `Theme.Holo`.
2. Stick with the regular `Theme.AppCompat` family of themes.
3. Figure out how to backport the look of Holo onto your own custom theme inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`. This may not be possible. If it is, it will *not* be easy. I'd estimate the level of effort as being best measured in developer-months.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the compatibility with older API versions while using Activity?  I personally think that the Holo/Jellybean look looks a lot better than material design.

Comment: @AngryCupcake274: "Is there a way to keep the compatibility with older API versions while using Activity?" -- um, `Activity` has been around since API Level 1 (Android 1.0).

Comment: :P I guess I assumed that if I changed the AppCompatActivity to an Activity the AppCompat elements would break.

Comment: @AngryCupcake274: Correct. This is why in option #1, I said that you have to "use a theme based off of Theme.Holo". Now, `Theme.Holo` itself only goes back to API Level 11. If you're aiming to support older than that, you're going to have problems.

Comment: I guess I have to use option 2 or 3 as I have elements with API level above my minSdkVersion.